# Creating a multiple choice option in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have created an HTML multiple choice question. I am facing a problem how to validate it. Below is the HTML code:

```html
<h1>JavaScript is ______ Language.</h1><br>
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="choice" value="Scripting"> Scripting
  <input type="radio" name="choice" value="Programming"> Programming
  <input type="radio" name="choice" value="Application"> Application
  <input type="radio" name="choice" value="None of These"> None of These
</form>
<button>Submit Answer</button>
```

When the user clicks the submit button, there should be an alert that will show a message based on what was selected.

- If no option was selected, the alert box should say `"please select choice answer"`.
- If the "Scripting" option was selected, the alert box should say `"Answer is correct !"`
- If an option different from "Scripting" is selected, the alert box should say `"Answer is wrong"`.

I want to create this validation in JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use onclick attribute and more js

1. attach event hander to your button
2. get radio elements value
3. compare

```js
var submitAnswer = function() {

  var radios = document.getElementsByName('choice');
  var val= "";
  for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
      if (radios[i].checked) {
         val = radios[i].value; 
         break;
       }
  }
  
  if (val == "" ) {
    alert('please select choice answer');
  } else if ( val == "Scripting" ) {
    alert('Answer is correct !');
  } else {
    alert('Answer is wrong');
  }
};
```

```html
<h1>JavaScript is ______ Language.</h1><br>
<form >
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="Scripting"> Scripting
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="Programming"> Programming
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="Application"> Application
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="None of These"> None of These
</form>
<button onclick="submitAnswer()">Submit Answer</button>
```

Comment: document.getElementsByName is buggy in Internet Explorer, I'd advise against getting in the habit of using it casually : http://quirksmode.org/dom/core/#t134

Answer (score 2):

```js
var submitAnswer = function() {

  var radios = document.getElementsByName('choice');
  var val= "";
  for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
      if (radios[i].checked) {
         val = radios[i].value; 
         break;
       }
  }
  
  if (val == "" ) {
    alert('please select choice answer');
  } else if ( val == "Scripting" ) {
    alert('Answer is correct !');
  } else {
    alert('Answer is wrong');
  }
};
```

```html
<h1>JavaScript is ______ Language.</h1><br>
<form >
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="Scripting"> Scripting
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="Programming"> Programming
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="Application"> Application
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="None of These"> None of These
</form>
<button onclick="submitAnswer()">Submit Answer</button>
```

## Some changes

I made some changes to the code above to make it more 'abstract'

```html
<h1>JavaScript is ______ Language.</h1><br>
<form id="d1">
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="Scripting"> Scripting
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="Programming"> Programming
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="Application"> Application
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="None of These"> None of These
</form>
<button onclick="submitAnswer(d1.choice.value, 'Scripting')">Submit Answer</button>

<script>
var submitAnswer = function(valore, rightanswer) {
if (valore == rightanswer) {
    alert("OK");
}
};
</script>
```

## Another, more complex example

```html
<div style="background-color:lightblue">
<h1>JavaScript is a <span id='a1'>______</span> Language.</h1><br>
<form id="d1">
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="Scripting"> Scripting
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="Programming"> Programming
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="Application"> Application
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="None of These"> None of These
<br>
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="validate(choice.value, 'Scripting', 'd1','a1')">
</form>
</div>
<div style="background-color:lightblue">
<h1>Python is a <span id='a2'>______</span> Language.</h1><br>
<form id="d2">
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="Scripting"> Scripting
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="Wonderful"> Wonderful
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="Application"> Application
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="None of These"> None of These
<br>
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="validate(choice.value, 'Wonderful', 'd2', 'a2')">
</form>
</div>

<script>
var validate = function(valore, rightanswer, form, span) {

var formname = document.getElementById(form)
var spanname = document.getElementById(span)

    spanname.innerHTML = rightanswer;

if (valore == rightanswer) {
    formname.innerHTML ="<div style='background-color:lightgreen'><h1>GREAT! YOU'RE RIGHT: The answer, in fact, was: " + rightanswer + "</h1></div>";
}
else {

    formname.innerHTML ="<div style='background-color:pink'><h1>Sorry, you where wrong: The answer was: " + rightanswer + "</h1></div>";
}
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `required` keyword. This prompts the user to choose a value, when the submit button is pressed without choosing any option. And always prefer to use

`<input type="submit" value="submit">` over  `<button>Submit Answer</button>`

while handling forms. Use the `onclick()` event handler to call your Javascript code.

```
<h1>JavaScript is ______ Language.</h1><br>
<form >
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="Scripting" required> Scripting
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="Programming"> Programming
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="Application"> Application
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="None of These"> None of These
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="validate()">
</form>
```

And the javascript part is as follows.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate() {
 var a= document.getElementByName("choice");
 for (var i = 0, i < a.length; i++) {
   if (a[i].checked) {
     if( a[i].value == "scripting" )
        alert("your answer is correct");
     else
        alert("your answer is not correct");
     break;
   } } }   
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here condition is showing in alert pop up box. but I want to show it in a html tag.
But after clicking submit button, innerHTML content showing a millisecond and then automatic remove the content. How selection will stay in innerHTML

```
document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML;
var submitAnswer = function() {

  var radios = document.getElementsByName('choice');
  var val= "";
  for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
      if (radios[i].checked) {
         val = radios[i].value; 
         break;
       }
  }

  if (val == "" ) {
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "please select choice answer";
  } else if ( val == "Scripting" ) {
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Answer is correct !"
  } else {
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Answer is wrong"
  }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add a function and event onClick so that whenever someone clicks on option submit button will appear.